# Windows 8.1 Microsoft Account doesn't exist. How to resolve?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, user-accounts

I'm trying to update my father's Windows 8 PC to 8.1 and then to 10. Unfortunately there's a bit of a mystery surrounding his Microsoft account login.

His user account has a password that he uses to login, but when I updated to 8.1 the process requested his MS account password and the login password didn't work. On reverting to 8.0 and going to the User Settings it has an option to sign in to the MS account but that also doesn't seem to share the login password. I've been to the live.com account page and it declares that the account doesn't exist.

I'm not sure how to proceed. I'd prefer to sort out his MS account rather than switching to a local account but it seems to be in some weird limbo where the PC thinks one is linked but the site doesn't recognise that the account exists.

Comment: the account might NOT exist.  from what I recall, it IS possible to log into W8 without creating a MS account.  Are you 100% sure that he had one in the first place?  Does he use it for anything else?

Comment: If there was never an MS account attached then I'd expect to be asked to add one. I'm not, it's just asking for the MS account password. As I said, the login password does not work so it certainly seems like there's some other account login associated.